# Tiled Map Collisions?

Tags: java, collision-detection, tile

I've been working on my own game for a couple weeks now and have gotten stuck on collisions. The game map is tiled (32*32 tiles) and I'm not sure where I should start for player - tile collisions. I have tried using rectangles but everytime it ended in a blank screen or a lot of errors.

My Main Class:

```
package net.Exploration.alk;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Explore_Main extends Applet implements Runnable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public final int TARGET_FPS = 60;
public final long OPTIMAL_TIME = 1000000000 / TARGET_FPS;
public static long lastFpsTime = 0;
public static int fps = 0;
public static int renderFps = 0;

private static JFrame frame;

public static final int res = 1;

public static double offsetY = 121, offsetX = 2;
public static int dir = 0;

public static boolean moving = false;
public static boolean run = false;

private Image screen;
public static Player player;

public Level level;

public static Dimension screenSize = new Dimension(700, 560);
public static Dimension pixel = new Dimension(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
public static Dimension Size;

public static String name = "Exploration Alpha 0.2";

public Explore_Main(){
    setPreferredSize(screenSize);
    addKeyListener(new Input());
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Explore_Main explore = new Explore_Main();

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(explore);
    frame.pack();

    Size = new Dimension(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());

    frame.setTitle(name);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    explore.start();
}

public void start(){
    requestFocus();

    //define classes
    level = new Level(1);
    player = new Player("billy bob");


    new Tile();

    run = true;
    new Thread(this).start();
}

public void stop(){
    run = false;
}

public void tick(double delta){

    frame.pack();

    player.tick(delta);
    level.tick(delta);

}

public void render(){

    Graphics g = screen.getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 800, 800);

    level.render(g, (int)offsetX, (int)offsetY, (pixel.width / Tile.size) + 2, (pixel.height / Tile.size) + 2);
    player.render(g);

    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawString("oX: " + (int)offsetX + " oY: " + (int)offsetY, 600, 515);
    g.drawString("FPS: " + renderFps, 600, 530);

    g = this.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(screen, 0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height, 0, 0,    pixel.width, pixel.height, null);
    g.dispose();

}

public void run() {
    screen = createVolatileImage(pixel.width, pixel.height);

    long lastLoopTime = System.nanoTime();

    while(run){

        long now = System.nanoTime();
        long updateLength = now - lastLoopTime;
        lastLoopTime = now;

        double delta = updateLength / (double)OPTIMAL_TIME;
        lastFpsTime += updateLength;
        fps++;

        if(lastFpsTime >= 1000000000){
            renderFps = fps;
            fps = 0;
            lastFpsTime = 0;
        }

        tick(delta);

        render();

        try{
            Thread.sleep((lastLoopTime - System.nanoTime() + OPTIMAL_TIME) / 1000000);
        }catch(Exception e){}

    }
}
}
```

Level class:

```
package net.Exploration.alk;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.tiled.TiledMap;

public class Level 
{
public int width = 100;
public int height =100;
public Background[][] backgroundvariable = new Background[width][height];
public Solid[][] solid = new Solid[width][height];
public Item[][]item = new Item[width][height];
//Level = Map
//Dpath is the first part of a levels name
public final String Dpath = "Resources/World/Level_";
public String path = Dpath;

private boolean[][] blocked;

public TiledMap map = null;

public Level(int id)
{
    path = Dpath + Integer.toString(id) + ".tmx";
    System.out.println(path);

    try{
        map = new TiledMap(path,false);
    }catch(SlickException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error Loading map!(Also might want to fix):");
    }
    for(int x = 0; x < backgroundvariable.length; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < backgroundvariable[0].length; y ++)
        {
            backgroundvariable[x][y] = new Background(new Rectangle(x * Tile.size, y * Tile.size,Tile.size,Tile.size),Tile.blank);
            solid[x][y] = new Solid(new Rectangle(x * Tile.size, y * Tile.size,Tile.size,Tile.size),Tile.blank);
            item[x][y] = new Item(new Rectangle(x * Tile.size, y * Tile.size,Tile.size,Tile.size),Tile.blank);

        }
    }

    loadWorld();

}
public void loadWorld()
{
    //declare layers
    int Background = map.getLayerIndex("background");
    int Solid = map.getLayerIndex("collision");
    int Item = map.getLayerIndex("items");


    for(int x = 0; x < backgroundvariable.length; x++)
    {
        for(int y = 0; y < backgroundvariable[0].length; y ++)
        {
        //terrain or background
        if(map.getTileId(x, y, Background) == 1){
            backgroundvariable[x][y].id = Tile.grass;
        }
        if(map.getTileId(x, y, Background) == 2){
            backgroundvariable[x][y].id = Tile.stone;
        }
        if(map.getTileId(x, y, Background) == 3){
            backgroundvariable[x][y].id = Tile.sky;
        }
        if(map.getTileId(x, y, Background) == 4){
            backgroundvariable[x][y].id = Tile.dirt;
        }

        //solids
        if(map.getTileId(x, y, Solid) == 1){
            solid[x][y].id = Tile.grass;


        //items
        {

        }

        }


    }}

}
public void tick(double delta)
{

}
public void render(Graphics g,int CamX,int CamY,int RenX,int RenY)
{
        for(int x = (CamX / Tile.size); x < (CamX / Tile.size) + RenX; x++){
            for(int y = (CamY / Tile.size); y < (CamY /Tile.size) + RenY; y++){
                if(x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < width && y < height){
                    backgroundvariable[x][y].render(g);;
            }
        }

        }
    }


}
```

Player Class:

```
package net.Exploration.alk;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class Player extends Rectangle{

    public double moveSpeed = 1.8;

    public static int[][] pImgRight = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}};
    public static int[][] pImgLeft = {{2, 0}, {3, 0}, {2, 0}};

    public static boolean isMoving = false;
    public static boolean up = false;
    public static boolean down = false;
    public static boolean left = false;
    public static boolean right = false;

    private Rectangle PlayerRect;

    public int aniFrame = 0;
    public int aniTime = 10;
    public int aniDelta = 0;

    public Player(String name){



        width = 32;
        height = 32;
        setBounds((Explore_Main.pixel.width / 2) - (width / 2), (Explore_Main.pixel.height / 2) - (height / 2), width, height);
    }

    public void tick(double delta){

        aniDelta ++;

        if(aniDelta >= aniTime){
            aniFrame ++;
            aniDelta = 0;
            if(aniFrame > 2){
                aniFrame = 0;
            }
        }

        if(up){
            Explore_Main.offsetY -= moveSpeed * delta;
        }

        if(down){
            Explore_Main.offsetY += moveSpeed * delta;
        }

        if(left){
            Explore_Main.offsetX -= moveSpeed * delta;
        }

        if(right){
            Explore_Main.offsetX += moveSpeed * delta;
        }

    }

    public void render(Graphics g){

        if(down){
            g.drawImage(Tile.Characters, this.x, this.y, x + width, y + height, pImgRight[aniFrame][0] * Tile.size, pImgRight[aniFrame][1] * Tile.size, pImgRight[aniFrame][0] * Tile.size + Tile.size, pImgRight[aniFrame][1] * Tile.size + Tile.size, null);
        }else if(up){
            g.drawImage(Tile.Characters, this.x, this.y, x + width, y + height, pImgRight[aniFrame][0] * Tile.size, pImgRight[aniFrame][1] * Tile.size, pImgRight[aniFrame][0] * Tile.size + Tile.size, pImgRight[aniFrame][1] * Tile.size + Tile.size, null);
        }else if(left){
            g.drawImage(Tile.Characters, this.x, this.y, x + width, y + height, pImgLeft[aniFrame][0] * Tile.size, pImgLeft[aniFrame][1] * Tile.size, pImgLeft[aniFrame][0] * Tile.size + Tile.size, pImgLeft[aniFrame][1] * Tile.size + Tile.size, null);
        }else if(right){
            g.drawImage(Tile.Characters, this.x, this.y, x + width, y + height, pImgRight[aniFrame][0] * Tile.size, pImgRight[aniFrame][1] * Tile.size, pImgRight[aniFrame][0] * Tile.size + Tile.size, pImgRight[aniFrame][1] * Tile.size + Tile.size, null);
        }else{
            g.drawImage(Tile.Characters, this.x, this.y, x + width, y + height, pImgRight[0][0] * Tile.size, pImgRight[0][1] * Tile.size, pImgRight[0][0] * Tile.size + Tile.size, pImgRight[0][1] * Tile.size + Tile.size, null);
        }


    }



}
```

Comment: Could you expand a bit more which problems are you facing?

Comment: How to accomplish solid tiles which the player cant pass through.